# Pullback in Descent for Vector Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I'm reading actually wiki's article about the Descent construction for vector bundles.

After motivating the idea as a generalization of "gluing" vector bundles over topological spaces there is introduced a more abstract approach:

Since the disjoint union $Y= \cup X_i $ one introduce the disjoint union of $X_{ij} = X_i \cap X_j$ as fiber product

$$Y \times_X Y$$

That's also ok since considering what happens on the intuitive intersection $X_{ij} = X_i \cap X_j$ is in light of category theory comparing the canonical projections $p_i: Y = \cup X_k \to X_i \subset X$

using equalizer of two copies of the projection $p$. The bundles on the $X_{ij}$ that have to be controlled are $V'$ and $V''$.

Now my question: In the article $V'$ and $V''$ are called the "pullbacks" to the fiber of $V$ via the two different projection maps to $X$.

I don't understand this interpretation of the $V'$ and $V''$. How they here are interpreted as pullbacks in categorical sense? Can anybody show the corresponding cartesian diagram for them? Furthermore, what is here "the fiber of $V$"? Especially what does the expression "pullback to the fiber of blabla" mean in this context?

Here the full article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_(mathematics)

Comment: $V'$ is the pullback of $V\to Y\to X$ along the second factor $Y\to X$ of $Y\times_X Y$.  Similarly $V''$.  You also have $X_{ij}\to Y\times_X Y$ which you can pull back $V'$ and $V''$ to, which is what the article is referring to.

Comment: @user10354138: Hi, thank you for your answer. To points aren't clear to me: you said "$V'$ in the pullback of $V \to Y \to X$ ***along*** the second factor ..." Firstly: What do you mean by the map $V \to Y$? $V$ is a fiber bundle over $X$ not $Y$, right? Or do you identify $V := \cup V_i$ as ***disjunct*** union of this $V_i$ before glueing? Secondly: What do you mean by along second factor? I know it that pull backs are constructed ***along some maps***. Do you mean here the "second" map $Y \to X$?

Comment: Also: What do they mean by pullback to the fiber? Pullback along $p: p^{-1}(x) \to \{x\}$?

Comment: Yes, the fiber is defined as pulling back along inclusion (here they are abusing it somewhat as $X_{ij}$ need not be a singleton), and I meant pulling back the bundle $p^*V$ along the one of the factor map of the fiber product $Y\times_X Y$.

Comment: @user10354138: Yes, it becomes clearer. One point: Which map do you mean by $V \to Y$? By definition $V$ is a bundle of $X$, right? Do you mean by $V$ also  the disjoint union $\cup V_i$, which is of course a $Y$ bundle? Or did I misunderstood you? Do you maybe implicitely by $V \to Y$ mean the induced $p^*V \to Y$?

Comment: I meant $p^*V\to Y\to X$.

Comment: @user10354138: btw: the categoretical way of speach "fiber of $V$ " means here always $f^*V$?